# Trying to save drop-down menu to database using PHP

Tags: php, sql

I have a form which has drop-down when I try to save the form to database using `PHP` the other fields are storing in the database but the select drop-down menu is not storing in the database it throws the below error:

> Notice: Undefined index: branch in D:\xampp\htdocs\form\insert.php on
>   line 8 Message Saved

I have the below code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>  
    <html>  
          <head>  
               <title></title>  
               <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />  
               <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
               <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  
          </head>  
          <body>  
               <br /><br />  
               <div class="container" style="width:500px;">  
                    <form id="submit_form">  
                         <label>Name</label>  
                         <input type="text" name="name" id="name" class="form-control" />  
                         <br /> 
                         <label>Select branch</label>
                         <select name="branch" id="branch" class="form-control">
                            <option selected hidden value="">Select Branch</option>
                            <option value="kalyan">kalyan</option>
                            <option value="mysuru">mysuru</option>
                            <option value="begur">begur</option>
                        </select> 
                         <label>Message</label>  
                         <textarea name="message" id="message" class="form-control"></textarea>  
                         <br />  
                         <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Submit" />  
                         <span id="error_message" class="text-danger"></span>  
                         <span id="success_message" class="text-success"></span>  
                    </form>  
               </div>  
          </body>  
     </html>  
     <script>  
     $(document).ready(function(){  
          $('#submit').click(function(){  
               var name = $('#name').val();  
               var message = $('#message').val(); 
               var branch = $('#branch').val(); 
               if(name == '' || message == '' || branch == '')  
               {  
                    $('#error_message').html("All Fields are required");  
               }  
               else  
               {  
                    $('#error_message').html('');  
                    $.ajax({  
                         url:"insert.php",  
                         method:"POST",  
                         data:{name:name, message:message},  
                         success:function(data){  
                              $("form").trigger("reset");  
                              $('#success_message').fadeIn().html(data);  
                              setTimeout(function(){  
                                   $('#success_message').fadeOut("Slow");  
                              }, 2000);  
                         }  
                    });  
               }  
          });  
     });  
</script>
```

This is the `PHP` code:

```
<?php  
 //insert.php  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rcis");  
 if(isset($_POST["name"]))  
 {  
      $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["name"]);  
      $message = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["message"]); 
      $branch = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, $_POST["branch"]);  
      $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_form(name, message,branch) VALUES ('".$name."', '".$message."', '".$branch."')";  
      if(mysqli_query($connect, $sql))  
      {  
           echo "Message Saved";  
      }  
 }  
 ?>
```

This is the table:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not passing the `branch` inside ajax function under data

```
data:{name:name, message:message},
```

Should be

```
data:{name:name, message:message, branch : branch},
```